# Conversion of Java Objects to XML for OptaPlanner Input

Tags: java, xml, optaplanner

I need to convert java objects being imported from the dB to the XML so that I could user it with Xstream in [OptaPlanner](http://www.optaplanner.org/). Is there any alternate way other than Hibernate to access the data from the dB. How to add more attributes for job scheduling.

Comment: What are you using - Spring/EJB? What have you tried before? Please be a little more detailed, it is hard to help this way.

Comment: Right now the input is in the form of XML I am parsing it to java Objects and then using Xstream Annotations I am letting it to be read by the SOLVER of Optaplanner, but I want it to be read from the dB. I have already converted the dB elements to Java Objects just need to either put them in a defined xml using a XSD.

Comment: Not sure I got that. Though if you want to access your database and get the objects you need, you can use Hibernate or just a simple JDBC connection also. I am pretty sure there are other options but these are the most straightforward. If you want object marshaling to XML, then JAXB is the way.

Comment: I have created java objects using simple JDBC statements itself, but i realized that inorder to feed them to optaplanner they need to be in a specific format defined in a xsd for optaplanner

Comment: Check this. You need something like this i think:  http://blog.sanaulla.info/2010/08/29/using-jaxb-to-generate-xml-from-the-java-xsd/

I will write an explanation for you if I have some more time today.

Comment: thanks @ragatskynet the link was very useful. I was searching for something like this only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

optaplanner-core works based on POJO's (javabeans). It's oblivious to the fact that in optaplanner-examples, those POJO's are being read/written to XML files by XStream (and it doesn't care). Similarly, you can use any other technology to store those POJO's:

- JPA (for example Hibernate-ORM, OpenJPA, ...) to store them into a database
- JDBC to store them into a database. Note: JDBC works with SQL statements, so you 'll need to manually map SQL records to POJO's.
- JAXB to store them in XML
- XStream to store them in XML (as the examples do it)
- Infinispan, mongodb, ... to store them in to a big data cloud. Note: might require manually mapping too, unless you use hibernate-ogm
- ...

OptaPlanner doesn't care, so it doesn't restrict you :)